# #ifndef/#define VS #pragma once

Tags: c++, классы, препроцессор

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём разница между двумя директивами и какую лучше использовать в коде?

**Файл MyClass.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

//class description

#endif
```

**Или**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//class description
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54033/discussion-on-question-by-neo-ifndef-define-vs-pragma-once).

Comment: @NickVolynkin то что комментарий о возможном дубликате также переносится в чат - это нормально?

Comment: @alexolut восстановил. Наверное не нормально, но не представляю, как это можно предотвратить.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Директива `#pragma once` является зависимой от реализации компилятора, а потому может не поддерживаться отдельными компиляторами, и будет просто игнорироваться.

Директивы `#ifndef` и `#define` являются стандартными директивами, а потому их использование в данном контексте будет одинаково для всех компиляторов.

Answer (score 16):

Фундаментальное отличие заключается в том, что `#pragma once` относится ко всему заголовочному файлу целиком. Изначальной идеей `#pragma once` было то, что в процессе обработки отдельной единицы трансляции компилятор (препроцессор) имеет право *даже и не искать и не открывать* второй раз заголовочные файлы, которые содержат `#pragma once`. Именно в этой форме когда-то и предлагалось стандартизовать `#pragma once` - как средство ускорения компиляции.

Include guards `#ifdef/#endif`, понятное дело, имеют право покрывать не весь заголовочный файл, т.е. эта пара в общем случае не относится ко всему файлу целиком. Это означает, что в общем случае компилятор будет вынужден найти и открыть заголовочный файл, чтобы включить участки, не попавшие внутрь `#ifdef/#endif`.

В то же время понятно, что компилятору не составляет никакого труда проанализировать содержимое заголовочного файла при первом прочтении и распознать явное идиоматическое использование `#ifdef/#endif`, прокрывающее весь файл целиком от начала до конца. В такой ситуации `#pragma once` не предоставляет никакой практической выгоды по сравнению с `#ifdef/#endif`. Именно по этой причине от стандартизации `#pragma once` в свое время отказались - как от фичи, не привносящей никакой дополнительной ценности (кроме, разве что, компактной записи и того, что, как заметили @vp_arth и @VladD, нет необходимости выдумывать уникальный идентификатор).

Соответственно, ответ очевиден - пользуйтесь стандартной функциональностью `#ifdef/#endif` и забудьте про нестандартный `#pragma once`. Может быть в каком-то случае вы заметите, что компилятор (препроцессор) не хочет оптимизировать обработку на основе анализа `#ifdef/#endif` и использование `#pragma once` действительно ускоряет компиляцию... Тогда, если для вас это критично - может быть стоит добавить в ваши файлы `#pragma once`.

Еще одно соображение против стандартизации `#pragma once` заключалось в том, что для обеспечения жесткой гарантии ее спецификации (т.е. строго единственного включения), необходимо иметь возможность надежно определять идентичность файла по указанному в директиве `#include` пути. Это задача в общем случае исключительно трудноразрешима во многих существующих файловых системах. Поэтому будьте осторожны с наивными пионерскими заявлениями типа "все современные компиляторы поддерживают `#pragma once`". Ни о какой поддержке строгой спецификации ни в одном компиляторе речи не идет. И, разумеется, ни о каких гарантиях одинаковости поведения между компиляторами речи не идет тоже. По этой причине, если вы таки соберетесь использовать `#pragma once` в своем коде, используйте ее *вместе* с include guards, а не *вместо* их.

**P.S.** Включение других заголовочных файлов обычно "кладут" внутрь вашего `#ifdef/#endif`. Им нет никакой причины находиться снаружи. Манерой оставлять их снаружи вы, возможно, рискуете подавить вышеупомянутую оптимизацию. Если уж вы пользуетесь `#ifdef/#endif`, то в подавляющем большинстве случаев они должны покрывать весь файл от начала до конца.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53986/discussion-on-answer-by-ant-ifndef-define-vs-pragma-once).

Comment: @vp_arth: От того, что вы повторите одно и то же сто раз оно не станет правдой. Мои аргументы подробно изложены в моем ответе. И они отнюдь не сводятся к "не в стандарте".

Answer (score 13):

## Переносимость

Множество компиляторов, не поддерживающих `#pragma once` на сегодняшний день стремится к пустому множеству. В основном там сейчас неразвиваемые либо заброшенные.

В enWiki есть [таблица](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once#Portability) со ссылками на источники. В этом списке только [PGI](http://www.pgroup.com/resources/docs.php) не поддерживает `#pragma once`.
Присутствующий в списке на ruWiki `OracleSolarisStudio` исправил это упущение в версии 12.5

## Ускорение компиляции

Этот плюс весьма призрачен. Ускорения компиляции от его использования вы можете не достичь, компиляторы умеют(gcc точно) оптимизировать и то, и то.

## Коллизии

Основной минус `include guards` - вы не можете гарантировать, что придумали уникальный идентификатор.

Если вы никогда не планируете подключать чужеродные библиотеки, можете придумать себе правило для `include guards` и жить спокойно.
В ином случае, они ломают всё то, для чего в `c++` существуют namespaces. Простого `MYCLASS_H` явно недостаточно, ведь он может быть уже определён в другой подключаемой библиотеке, либо если вы и пишете библиотеку - в клиентском коде.
Вам придётся выдумывать действительно уникальные идентификаторы, навроде `__VENDOR_PACKAGE_MYCLASS` или `__MYCLASS_%TIMESTAMP%`, чтобы исключить вероятность коллизии.

## Резюме

Разумеется, что именно использовать в вашем проекте - решать только вам. Однако, очевидно, что нет никаких причин не использовать более лаконичную версию, кроме фанатичной "`Отсутствует в стандарте`".

---

**PS:** *Вы некорректно применяете `include guards` - они обязательно должны охватывать весь файл целиком, иначе компилятор никак не сможет оптимизировать их, чтобы не запускать препроцессор для этого файла повторно.*

Comment: Добавлю ещё момент с рефакторингом - при изменнии имени файла придется следить ещё и за `#ifdef`, в отличии от варианта с `#pragma`.

Comment: Несомненно, тут играет роль человеческий фактор. Вплоть до `ifndef __FILE_H define _FILE_H`