# Использование pragma once внутри ifndef

Tags: c++, c, include

Есть похожий вопрос [Зачем используются вместе #pragma once и header guards?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1373319/176217), но там рассматривается вариант `pragma once` снаружи, который потенциально может решать проблему повторных включений более оптимально, как описано в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/630597/176217) на другой вопрос.

Но в каких ситуациях разумно использовать обратный вариант, когда `pragma once` находится уже внутри `ifndef`? Примеры подобных использований можно найти даже в заголовочных файлах Microsoft, например,

`c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\atlmfc\include\atlcom.h`:

```
...
#ifndef __ATLCOM_H__
#define __ATLCOM_H__

#pragma once
...
```

Ведь пара `ifndef` + `define` будет работать везде и смысла наличия внутри `pragma once` как будто бы нет. Но даже если `pragma once` будет использоваться для каких-то оптимизаций (например, запоминания пути к файлу, чтобы больше его не включать), почему его поместили внутри, а не снаружи от `ifndef`?

Comment: Нахождение `pragma once` снаружи менее оптимально, так как в этом случае в компиляторах, которые её не поддерживают, она будет обрабатываться каждый раз при вставке заголовочного файла в единицу трансляции. А если используется gcc с выпиленной поддержкой этой прагмы, то в нем не будет срабатывать встроенный механизм автоматической оптимизации повторного включения заголовочного файла на основании header guards, так как он требует отсутствия токенов перед ними.

Comment: Имхо, они просто по незнанию поставили.

Comment: @AlexF согласно стандарту нераспознанные `pragma` будут проигнорированы - *Any pragma that is not recognized by the implementation is ignored*. Т.е. предупреждение, конечно, может быть, но это уже вопрос к конкретному компилятору, да и подавить его, скорее всего, должно быть можно каким-нибудь ключиком.

Comment: [Difference between pragma once inside and outside include guards?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5382404)

Comment: @wololo кроме странного случая с `undef` разницы между способами особо не видно в ответах на enSO.

Comment: @user7860670 а есть ссылка, где про начальные токены описано? Потенциально можно пару условных include-guard друг за другом разместить. Т.е. надо ещё и хвост файла иметь в виду.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/Guard-Macros.html